# Getting no value when trying to insert $_POST to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, http-post, mysql-real-escape-string, mysql-insert-id

I am making a quiz system and when I try to insert the question text, from the $_POST of the HTML form, it just inserts an empty value, and the question_id stays zero:

```
        Question text: <br />
                    <textarea name="qtext" rows="2" style="width:200px; height:100px;" name="qst"></textarea> <br />
```

### PHP Part

```
$post_qtext = $_POST['qst'];
$post_qtext = mysql_real_escape_string($post_qtext);
    $q_insertquestions = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `questions` (`question`,`type`) VALUES ('$post_qtext','1')");
$q_lastquestioninserted = mysql_insert_id($q_insertquestions);
```

question_id in the table is int(11)
question in mysql is varchar(60)

Comment: Please stop using the `mysql_*` functions, they are no longer supported and the deprecation process has started. Look into **mysqli** or **PDO** for a more secure and supported function set.

Comment: Your textarea is named `qtext` but you are reading from the nonexistent `$_POST['qst']`

Comment: You've given the text area a "name" attribute twice, remove one of them for a start.

Comment: Turn on display_errors, and you will be seeing undefined index notices, which would identify the problem.  `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski The problem is that he's given it a "name", twice.

Comment: @EM-Creations Indeed - I didn't scroll far enough right

Comment: But wouldn't it just record the last instance of name?

Comment: @Strawberry Probably, the first, or just cock up all together.

Comment: Question text: <br />
      <textarea name="qst" rows="2" style="width:200px; height:100px;"></textarea> <br />

But it's still empty

Answer (score 4):

The textarea has `name="qtext"` but the PHP has `$_POST['qst'];`.

You need to access the array index that is the same as the name of your field.

… I now see it *also* has `name="qst"`. You aren't allowed to use the same attribute twice on a single element. Browsers may or may not recover from this error. You should make use of [a validator](http://validator.w3.org).

Comment: I fixed the name issues but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You have written name twice in your HTML page change it and also change ur text area name to qst

```
<textarea name="qst" rows="2" style="width:200px; height:100px;"></textarea> <br />
```

Comment: Now it's ok but there's a problem also with the mysql_insert_id()

Comment: try to avoid mysql_* queries, write simple mysql_query...Because sometimes it wont support..

Answer (score 0):

Because you added two names for `textarea`

Remove `name="qst"` from `textarea`

```
<textarea name="qtext" rows="2" style="width:200px; height:100px;"></textarea>
```

And Do like this:

```
$post_qtext = $_POST['qtext'];
```